# How to hide a control from the form while designing in visual studio?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am designing a settings form for my application as shown below:

A tree view with multiple nodes at the left and I want to have one GroupBox for each node to be displayed at the right whenever a node is selected. I have designed my group box with necessary controls for the first node. The question is, how do I design an another group box in the same place when another item is already there. Is there a way to hide a control from a form during design time?

[image: settings form with treeview and groupbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always just changed the Z-Order of the `GroupBox` or `Panel` by right clicking on it and sending it to back. Just make sure when you add the other `GroupBoxes` that you add them to the same `Parent`. Make their `Visible` property `False` and then display the `GroupBox` you want at runtime by making it Visible.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KezhA.png]

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Changed answer to be more relevant.

EDIT #2: I missed the VB tag, translating this should be a trivial task anyway.

If you extend `GroupBox` like this, you'll have a stock GroupBox which will hide itself at design time.

```
public class myGroupBox : GroupBox
{
    public myGroupBox() { InitializeComponent(); }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (DesignMode) this.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

NOTE: This should work for almost any non-sealed control.

Comment: 2 things he is asking for Vb.net and how is he going to edit/add his controls in the new GroupBox if it is hidden. You would need to be able to turn the property off/on in it's property box

Comment: I missed the VB tag. Control can still be selected from the controls list above the property grid I think, it's just invisible but it's still there :D